# AngularJs - Expression is not being valuated correctly

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-init, ng-init

I have defined an expression in `ng-init` which is being evaluated to false but when I assign it to a variable, its being evaluated to true.

```
 <div class="small-6 medium-6 large-6 cell" ng-init="disablePMPR = !((roleControl.disableBlock) && (roleControl.block == 1) && (roleControl.userRole == 'PMPR'))">
```

This expression is evaluated to false, which is correct ==>

```
   !((roleControl.disableBlock) && (roleControl.block == 1) && (roleControl.userRole == 'PMPR'))
```

But **disablePMPR** is evaluated to true.
Is there other way to define this expression ?

Comment: It is hard to tell without knowing what all of those values do. Have you tried removing the `!` Logical Not?

Comment: Did you check disablePMPR inside the roleControlor or in the scope?

Comment: if `((roleControl.disableBlock) && (roleControl.block == 1) && (roleControl.userRole == 'PMPR'))` evalutes to false than `!((roleControl.disableBlock) && (roleControl.block == 1) && (roleControl.userRole == 'PMPR'))` will be true. what is wrong in this.

Comment: The expression is being evaluated to **true** and I have put the _!_ to make it false. The variable **disablePMPR** is having value TRUE

Comment: Please, don't use ng-init. It is a bad practice. Just move it to the controller.

Comment: You mean,!((roleControl.disableBlock) && (roleControl.block == 1) && (roleControl.userRole == 'PMPR'))  evaluated to false , but disablePMPR is getting true value.

Comment: @HimahshuShekhar yes exactly